# Testing a C++0x Project with CppUnit using Clang

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, cppunit

I want to use CppUnit to test my software project, which currently makes extensive use of C++0x/C++11 features like `std::shared_ptr` and `auto` variables. As the project uses these features, and I'm building it with `clang`, I need to pass the `-stdlib=libc++` flag when I compile it. However using this version of the standard library prevents me from using CppUnit which demands I use the `libstdc++` standard library.

Is there any way I can make my testing code and program code coexist using these separate libraries or is there some other way I can use CppUnit to test this code?

Comment: It is a problem with the cppunit build system: I'm currently looking into it and hope to provide a solution for 1.14

Comment: So I explored it a bit with development versions of cppunit, clang and libc++ and it looks like everything works if you pass -stdlib=libc++ and make sure that the DllPluginTester links against libc++-abi.